# Disable Just-In-Time Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

I have installed the following components of SQL Server 2012:

- management tools - complete
- Client Tools Connectivity
- Client Tools SDK
- Client Tools Backwards Compatibility

Now, "Just-In-Time Debugging" runs every time there is a error in the browser. I want to disable it but here it is said (normally) that I should open my visual studio:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

My problem is that I have never installed visual studio and there is no such in my computer (I did not found) - only some folders of visual studio with other files, but not exe file, where to start id.

I am using windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Management Studio is based on the Visual Studio - which is why you can find some system files but no `devenv.exe`

Comment: @Dennis Yes, it is "powered by Visual Studio" but then how to disable this "Just-In-Time Debugging"?

Comment: I only intended to comment why you had some elements of Visual Studio installed on your computer as you can easily find an answer to disabling JIT debugging by searching Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick search on Google revealed the answer.

> Open Start > Control Panels > Internet Options: Advanced
>
> - Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)
> - Disable Script Debugging (Other)

**Reference**

- [Getting RID of Just-In-Time debugger](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/a52eb0ae-bcd8-4043-9661-d5fc3aa5167c/)